# How do I change text color in Excel when an IF statement evaluates to true

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula:

```
=IF(OR(date1="",date2=""),21,date2-date1)
```

I am familiar with conditional formatting, but in this case I am pretty sure it won't function to correctly to do what I want to do.

I want the 21 to change to aquamarine, BUT only if that is because the formula evaluated the OR statement as true.  If the date2-date1 is 21 I DON'T want it to change colors.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel Conditional Formatting Help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011152/excel-conditional-formatting-help)

Comment: except that I explicitly stated conditional formatting will not do what I am asking to do here.

Comment: You are incorrect. Your conditional formatting rule is just =OR(date1="",date2=""). Or perhaps (you are somewhat contradictory in your setup statement and your followup statement) =AND(A1=21,date2-date1<>21).

Comment: except I tried that and every single cell gets formatted regardless of the evaluation of that statement.  I suspect that is because date1 and date2 are named columns, so they are only blank in certain rows and conditional formatting is evaluating the entire named column.

Comment: Go back and read the duplicate I noted, or any of the many Conditional Formatting questions on stackoverflow. It will show how you need to align your formulas with your actual cell references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a second formula that only returns TRUE or FALSE instead of your values of 21 and date2-date1.  Reference that column in your Conditional Formatting, then hide it.

I'm not sure how your formulas look, but it's quite possible.

[image]

As Grade 'Eh' Bacon was saying, you need to use formulas that return true or false in a way that returns true for the condition you want.  One thing to check is that your formulas to make sure that they are not pointing at a fixed cell: I forgot the same thing when I was making this sample.

Comment: I am not sure how that helps, even just using conditional formatting on the column and setting it to apply the format where that formula evaluates true colors EVERYTHING.  

I even tried using IF(OR(ISBLANK(date1),ISBLANK(date2)) and applying it to the cells only on that condition and still EVERYTHING gets formatted.

Comment: quotes make all the difference.  It wasn't working for me when I was using "TRUE".  No idea why it was highlighting everything though.